# Accessing global variable from other JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

This is my main file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function Page() {
    this.menu = new Menu();
    this.management = new Management();
    this.text = "text";
  }
window.Page= Page();
});
```

Now I want to access the Page from every other JS file:

I tried this:

```
console.log(Page.text);
```

Gives me : `Uncaught ReferenceError: Page is not defined`

Tried this:

```
console.log(window.Page.text);
```

Gives me : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can't you move the main function outside of `document.ready` ?

Comment: My "guess" would be that `window.Page = ..` is not executed prior to the console.log statements - **the ReferenceError on `Page.text` will *only* occur if the window.Page property is *not* set**. Remember that `ready` is an asynchronous operation/callback.

Comment: (Only variables lookup will result in a ReferenceError; failing property lookups evaluate to `undefined` - so accessing `window.Page` evaluates to `undefined` and `(undefined).text` results in the TypeError. However, the ReferenceError is the thing to pay attention to.)

Comment: I am getting undefined now for the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that within the Page function you are not creating any new object on the global context. You are creating a new Menu and new Management instance but on the current context.

Plus by calling the Window.Page = Page(), you are assigning the result of the Page function (which is void) to the window.Page object.

I suggest you do something like :

```
//- from any js file 
    function createPage() {
            var newPage = { title : 'new page', count : '2' };
            return newPage;
          }
    window.Page = createPage();
```

...

```
//- and from other js file
    $(document).ready(function () {                
    alert(window.Page.title);
    });
```

Note, I have replaced your menu and management properties with dummy content for this sample. Sample available @ [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyNR6/)

Update : Code has been updated to illustrate the multiple js file proper usage.

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't get your point, of course you need to wait this object has been created before accessing it or ensute you create when needed. I would say that if multiple JS library are involved, you should consider accessing any content on document.ready state, cause that will ensure all libraries will be loaded. In any case, if you are accessing values without any kind of "thinking" you will never be free from errors cause you don't know in which order the libraries are loaded. Also by considering the initial question, I think this answer is correct (and this comment should help for the sync. issue)

Comment: While synchronization is important (and I suspect the original error was related to such), the original code *would* have create a global property - namely `window.Page` - if/when it ran. The value assigned to `window.Page` is irrelevant in causing (or not causing) a ReferenceError. (While an `undefined` value is not very useful it merely exposes the additional problem(s)).

Comment: I am sorry to say so but original code would NOT have created a proper value cause the window.Page was set with the "return" of a void method, so it is a kind of relevant :)

Comment: This answer still fails to address the [initial] ReferenceError and the initial paragraph makes it sound like the issues is about scope; it is not. It is about execution order.

Comment: Also, the result of a function without a return value is `undefined` (one expression which will evaluate to such value is `void(..)`, but the value of such evaluation is *not* "Void").

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `window.Page = new Page();`.

Comment: .. isn't this similar to what he already has? (Note that it is a ReferenceError.)

Comment: If the window property `Page` was assigned *any* value - even `undefined` - then `Page.text` would not result in a ReferenceError. Because it does throw a ReferenceError, it can be deduced that `window.Page = ..` was *not executed* at all; or, at least not before the console.log statements.

Comment: Now console log prints out `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Function definitions don't need to be inside the `document.ready()` function. Only immediate actions that need to take place when the DOM is ready need to be put in there. So move the function to the toplevel.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
window.Page = new Page();
```

or

```
function Page(){
   this.menu = new Menu();
   this.management = new Management();
   this.text = "text";
   return this;
}
window.Page = Page();
```

Then make sure other scripts don't try to use window.Page before it has been declared. You declare it in document.ready() callback function, so it's only going to be accessible once the DOM is ready and the callback function has been fired.

Edit:

without the context I'm not sure this is exactly what you're trying to do, but I think you just need a global Page object with some properties/methods. The easiest way to create it would be

```
window.Page = {
    menu : new Menu(),
    management = new Management(),
    text = "text"
};
```

without the document.ready() wrapper. 
Now obviously `Menu` and `Management` need to be defined before this code is executed. If any of these functions relies on DOM just move all your scripts to the end of the document. Any script that needs access to window.Page has to be included after this one.

Comment: Now console log prints out `undefined`.